# Redirect only Posts after changing permalinks

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a Wordpress website that have many posts and pages

- the posts links format is : `MYWEBSITE.COM/POST_NAme`
- the pages link Format is  : `MYWEBSITE.COM/PAGE_NAME`

Now I want to change only the permalink of posts to:

`MYWEBSITE.COM/blog/POST_NAme`

When this is done , the old links of posts (`MYWEBSITE.COM/POST_NAme`) give a 404 error. How can I make a redirection only for posts from (without changing pages links):

`MYWEBSITE.COM/POST_NAme` to `MYWEBSITE.COM/blog/POST_NAme`

Answer (score 0):

Use the redirection plugin it is easy to use and helps you to redirect your pages.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

thank you for you reply ,
when i go to settings->permalinks  then i change to custom permalink 
MYWEBSITE.com/blog/%postname%/

now all the posts published in social media and emails will not work , because their link is MYWEBSITE.com/%postname%/

the SOLUTION is

redirect links by regular expressions from MYWEBSITE.com/XXXXX to MYWEBSITE.com/blog/XXXXX

but the problem now that the pages have the same regex so the page also will be redirected to /blog/pagename and ten i will have 404 error ,
i want that the regexe applied to posts only